# Is it correct that static library from xcode 11 is not acceptable in xcode10

Tags: ios, xcode

I get error showing not find symbol ,when use lib from xcode11 in xcode10. I dont know if its correct. Lib users may not like changing from 10 to 11.

Comment: please look into this thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/117346#364519

Comment: Does it just mean if universal lib from xcode11 is not working in xcode10 environment...

Comment: It's not generally correct, no.  It's probably more to do with what `min_ios_version` it was compiled with, for example (i.e. conditional compilation of the objects).